# Dynamically embedding video in pdf

Tags: java, dynamicpdf

I have used **ibex** library for dynamic pdf creation but what I want now is to embed a video file dynamically to the pdf but don't know if it is possible. If it's possible please suggest how to and if not possible by **ibex**, then suggest another open source library.

Answer (score 1):

Embedding video is not possible using IBEX library.

Please check [Ibex Programmers Guide](http://www.xmlpdf.com/builds/ibex.pdf) for supported features.

Answer (score 0):

PDF file format itself support to [add an attachment inside the PDF file](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/links-attachments-pdfs.html).

But ibex do not have such API yet, based on its [guide](http://www.xmlpdf.com/builds/ibex.pdf), unfortunately.

Alternative solutions

Option 1. `iText` - Try iText API as [specified here](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-attach-files-to-a-pdf), which looks like

- Add attachment in the PDF file

```
PdfFileSpec fs = PdfFileSpec.createEmbeddedFileSpec(pdfDoc, …);
pdfDoc.addFileAttachment("specificname", fs);
```

- Add a link to open the attached file

```
PdfTargetDictionary target = new PdfTargetDictionary(PdfName.P);
target.setName("specificname");
PdfAction action = PdfAction.createGoToE(PdfExplicitDestination.createFit(1), false, target);
```

Notes.

- `Cost` - iText can be used for free in situations where you also distribute your software for free. As soon as you want to use iText in a closed source, proprietary environment, you have to pay for your use of iText.
- `Disclaimer` - I have no connection with iText

Option 2. `Apache PDF Box` - following the [example here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/workingwithattachments.html)

A PDF can contain references to external files via the file system or a URL to a remote location. It is also possible to embed a binary file into a PDF document.

```
PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode efTree = new PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode();

//first create the file specification, which holds the embedded file
PDComplexFileSpecification fs = new PDComplexFileSpecification();
fs.setFile( "Test.txt" );
InputStream is = ...;
PDEmbeddedFile ef = new PDEmbeddedFile(doc, is );
//set some of the attributes of the embedded file
ef.setSubtype( "test/plain" );
ef.setSize( data.length );
ef.setCreationDate( new GregorianCalendar() );
fs.setEmbeddedFile( ef );

//now add the entry to the embedded file tree and set in the document.
Map efMap = new HashMap();
efMap.put( "My first attachment", fs );
efTree.setNames( efMap );
//attachments are stored as part of the "names" dictionary in the document catalog
PDDocumentNameDictionary names = new PDDocumentNameDictionary( doc.getDocumentCatalog() );
names.setEmbeddedFiles( efTree );
doc.getDocumentCatalog().setNames( names );
```

Note

- `PDFBox` is under Apache License 2